# How to make updates in multiple tables within many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a many-to-many relationship and I'm trying to update two tables by one click. One is for `appUser` and the other one is for `userLinks`.

My problem is I always get `appUser` data and never get `userLinks` data.

The model classes:

```
public class AppUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public List<UserLink> userLinks { get; set; }
}

public class UserLink
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string linkUrl { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public AppUser GetUser { get; set; }

    public Guid LinkId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LinkId")]
    public Link GetLink { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string linkIcon { get; set; }
    public string linkName { get; set; }
    public int ordr { get; set; }
    public bool IsPdf { get; set; } = false;
    public List<UserLink> userLinks { get; set; }

}
```

View model:

```
public class VMUserProfile
{
    public AppUser appUser { get; set; }
    public List<UserLink> userLinks { get; set; }
    public List<Link> links { get; set; } 
}
```

View:

```
@model VMUserProfile          

<form asp-action="EditProfile" asp-route-id="@Model.appUser.Id" method="post">
...
<ul id="linkList" class="list-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model.userLinks.Where(w => w.UserId == Model.appUser.Id).ToList())
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    @Html.Raw(item.GetLink.linkIcon)
                </div>
                <input asp-for="@item.linkUrl" id="@item.Id" class="form-control" placeholder="@item.GetLink.linkName" type="text" />
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-times-circle deleteLi"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
...
</form>
```

And here are the view look and the debug result

[image: view]

and notice in the network section how the `formdata` contains the URLs but I never receive them in the controller action the debug result returns null

[image: debug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of binding for the view model won't work for the object list (user links).

To bind a list of objects, MVC has a convention for it. Which is, you should use the index position of the list item.

```
@model VMUserProfile 

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit profile";
}

<form asp-action="EditProfile" asp-route-id="@Model.appUser.Id" method="post">

     <ul id="linkList" class="list-group">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.userLinks.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                     @Html.Raw(Model.userLinks[i].GetLink.linkIcon)
                  </div>

                  @*solution*@
                  <input asp-for="userLinks[i].linkUrl" id="@Model.userLinks[i].Id" class="form-control" placeholder="@Model.userLinks[i].GetLink.linkName" type="text"/>
                  <input type="hidden" asp-for="userLinks[i].Id"/>
                 
                 <div class="input-group-text">
                     <i class="far fa-times-circle deleteLi"></i>
                 </div>
               </div>
           </li>
        }
     </ul>

     <input type="submit" name="Edit" class="btn-success">

</form>
```

The filter you've added to the view model on the view,

```
Model.userLinks.Where(w => w.UserId == Model.appUser.Id).ToList()
```

That should go to **[HTTPGet]** EditProfile (or something else) action.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult EditProfile()
{
    var appUser = Get_AppUser();
    var userLinks = Get_UserLinks();

    var model = new VMUserProfile
    {
        appUser = appUser,
        userLinks = userLinks.Where(w => w.UserId == appUser.Id).ToList() //filter should be here
     };
        
   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try again after changing the UserLinks to `List<String>` instead of `List<UserLink>`.

**Updated Answer**

View:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.userLinks.Count; i++)
  {
     <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                    </div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.userLinks[i].Id)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.userLinks[i].linkUrl)
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="far fa-times-circle deleteLi"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
```

Controller Get:

Assign data to Userlinks as `Model.userLinks.Where(w => w.UserId == Model.appUser.Id).ToList()`

Controller Post:

[image]

Id will be 0 for new Url and already exist urls are accompanied with their ids.

Comment: I need UserLinks as it is for another context. moreover, I need urls and Ids, and I need also the possibility to get new urls without Ids. so I update urls with ids and I insert urls without ids.

Comment: If the user clicks on the yellow button they can add new urls without Ids. and the already exist urls are accompanied with ids and in that case they can be updated if any